# Visual Studio 2017 VB.Net trap mouse right click in multiline textbox not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to trap the mouse click in a multiline textbox.

The code traps for a left button click, but doesn't trap for a right button click (never calls the subroutine).

The textbox has ShortCutsEnabled set to false.  If I set it to True, I get the typical copy/paste/etc. window.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub User_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TxtBx.MouseClick

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        ' do stuff for left button click
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        ' do stuff for right button click
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wrong event, Click is generated with the left button.  Use the MouseUp event instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Hans. That worked just as I needed.  You might want to "answer" the question, so I can close it out.

Comment: I just realized that the while the left button sets the current line in a multiline textbox, apparently, the right button does not.  Is that correct?  Should I open a new question on how to get the currentline when right button is pressed?

Comment: I figured out how to fine the correct line.  All is good.  Thank you.